# View 'information_schema.SCHEMATA' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them

Tags: mysql

After upgrading to MySQL 8  getting this error

`ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'information_schema.SCHEMATA' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them`

when running

`show databases;`

Does anyone has an idea what is going on?

I've tried set to `sql_mode=''` and restarting the DB, but it doesn't help.

Comment: It feels like it might be a rights issue, can you connect to it using root instead if you aren't already?

Comment: I connected as a root user

Comment: What steps did you take to do this upgrade? Have you tried connecting with MySQL Workbench?  Perhaps you can backup your data first, and then take a look at the Information_scheme using MySQL Wokbench and see if you can find the offending tables.

Comment: What OS are you running and what are the full version numbers pre and post upgrade? How did you run the upgrade? Have you tried [`mysqld --upgrade=FORCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-what-is-upgraded.html#:~:text=Perform%20step%201%20as%20necessary%2C%20and%20force%20step%202)?

Comment: @user1191247 We are on CentOS 7, pre-upgrade version MySQL 5.7.44, upgraded version  8.0.35. I didn't use `mysql --upgrade=FORCE`.

Comment: Check the error log for any errors from startup. Make sure you have a full backup of your data and then try forcing the upgrade. Note it is `mysqld`, not `mysql`, for the upgrade command.